# How to recover Windows 7 files

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I want to recover Windows 7 files installed on my C: drive. Ubuntu is installed on my D: drive.

How can I recover files on my Windows installation?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: What do you understand by recover? Have you accidentally deleted some files?

Comment: @user3121023 The version that I am using is ubuntu 12.01

Comment: @MadMike , yes I have deleted them accidently

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PhotoRec application from the `testdisk` package to do this. It's in Ubuntu archives, so it's easy to install. It'll most likely be able to recover everything for you. However, data recovery is serious business, so please do read the documentation and take your time before you begin. PhotoRec won't cause any damage, but testdisk (another application in the package) can. If possible, you'll probably want to create a backup of your "C:" partition before you begin. It will require that you have some storage with at least as much free space as the size of C: though.

Comment: +1 and thank you for your efforts to help me I will try them

Comment: My pleasure. There is a reason why I know these tools; I've had use for them. I know the feeling :)